# How to make a draggable item from a draggable item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a window that is draggable and I want to make the document that this window has to be independent and it can be dragged and when dropped the element is copied to where it was dragged and for it to also stay in the window. Basically when what is supposed to do is you drag the document out of the window into anywhere in your screen and when you stop dragging, the document is copied and you have a document on the window and one on your screen. The one on the screen can't be copied but can be dragged. How do I do it?

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("documento"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("docwindow"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV: 
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        // stop moving when mouse button is released:
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

```css
#janela,
#docwindow,
#BlueWindow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 38%;
    left: 100px;
}

#docwindowheader,
#BlueWindowheader {
    height: 7%;
    background: rgb(30, 87, 153);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}

#closeDocs,
#closeBlue {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 4.2%;
    right: 1%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#docsHeadTexto,
#JoanaPTexto {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px grey;
    font-size: 95%;
    top: 25%;
}

#DocImg {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

img#DocImg {}

#bottomWindowDocs {
    background-color:pink;
    height: 80%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
}

#DocEx {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 4%;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#DocEx {
    z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="janelas" id="docwindow">
                <div id="docwindowheader">
                    <header class="windowTop">
                        <h1 id="docsHeadTexto">Documents</h1>
                        <img id="closeDocs" class="X" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-dialog-close-icon.png" alt="X" onclick="closeMain()">
                    </header>
                </div>

                <div id="bottomWindowDocs">
                    <div class="documents">
                        <div id="documento">
                            <img id="DocImg" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/file.png" alt="doc">
                            <h1 id="DocEx">Doc-example</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!----<div id="DocExemplo" S>
                  <header class="windowhead">
                      Documento exemplo
                      <img class="X" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180402/dwe/kisspng-computer-icons-social-media-email-webmail-cancel-button-5ac240963875f3.0504665115226799582313.jpg" alt="X" onclick="closeMain()">
                      <button id="share">share</button>
                      <button id="back">back</button>
                  </header>
                  <div id="corpo">
                      <h4>Este é um exemplo de Documento</h4>
                  </div>
              </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193428/discussion-on-question-by-rui-fernando-how-to-make-a-draggable-item-from-a-dragg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate the basic functionality using [jQuery's draggable()](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable), check this [demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/d8xoa26c/).

Here's the JS you would need to allow dragging one element with children that may be dragged and dropped separately:

```js
$('#doc-container').droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  cursor: 'move',
  greedy: true,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui);
    $(ui.draggable).removeClass("out-of-box").addClass("in-box");
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
  }
});

$('#larger-drop-target').droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  cursor: 'move',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).removeClass("in-box").addClass("out-of-box");
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
  }
});

$("#doc-container, .draggable").draggable({});
```

My sample uses the following HTML layout:

```html
<div id="larger-drop-target">
  <div id="doc-container" class="ui-widget-header droppable">
    <header class="windowTop">
      <h1 id="docsHeadTexto">Documents</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="draggable" style="left:0;" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
      Doc Example
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS Code:

```css
#larger-drop-target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.draggable {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#doc-container {
  height: 200px;
}

.in-box {
  background: #FEE;
}

.out-of-box {
  background: #EFE;
}
```

Some explanatory words:

- `droppable()` defines those elements that may accept elements to be dragged onto. In the sample I could not use the HTML "body" element as this wouldn't work in a fiddle so I decided to wrap the `#doc-container` in the larger container `#larger-drop-target`. The `.detach()` and `.attachTo()` makes sure the element's parent is removed and assigned to the current drop target, otherwise child elements would still move with their parent even if they have been dropped outside of it.
- `draggable()` defines those elements that may be dragged around.
- the classes applied to the dropped elements are just for demonstration purpose; elements that have been dropped on the `#doc-container` appear red, those dropped outside of it are green.
- the `position: absolute` for dragged elements was necessary as otherwise elements would constantly move around whenever one element was moved. If you need several "documents" in your container, give each a fitting `left: X00px;` style

**Update 1:**

You may clone each element as soon as it leaves the parent container and when dragged back remove it using class checks and `.clone()` / `.remove()`:

```js
$('#doc-container').droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  cursor: 'move',
  greedy: true,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass('out-of-box')) {
      ui.draggable.remove();
    } else {
      $(ui.draggable).removeClass("out-of-box").addClass("in-box");
      ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
    }

  }
});

$('#larger-drop-target').droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  cursor: 'move',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("in-box")) {
      var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
      clone.removeClass("in-box").addClass("out-of-box");
      clone.detach().appendTo($(this)).draggable({});
      ui.draggable.draggable({
        revert: true
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/ouw10xzL/) showing the changed version.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that. Will sure help me as hell. How about the option of when dropped it still remains in the container and also on the place it was dropped like a copy

Comment: @RuiFernando check the following [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/ouw10xzL/) that also handles cloning the doc.

Comment: I'm not really being able to use this in my code can you plz do it using my code? @SachaM78

Comment: And i guess what you call the `larger-drop-target` in your code is the whole page in mine so maybe it should be the `body` or `html`

Comment: @RuiFernando that's exactly what I wrote in my answer in the `droppable` statement ;-). Could you try to set up a Fiddle with your code that shows how far you got and I'll finish it?

Comment: Yeah sure i'll try to

Comment: i know it doesn't work in the fiddle because of that thing you said of the body not working in a fiddle but i can drag the window but can't drag the document

Comment: You did not include jQuery and jQuery UI as libraries in your Fiddle (you need to use the "Resources" tab and the pointing down arrow in the JS section to add additional libraries) so the dragging would not work. As you use a lot of `position:absolute;` in your setup, the HTML body in my first test did not have a height at all so dragging onto the body would not be possible, so you will need to somehow set the drop area to a sufficient heights to allow dropping items. Here's a working version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/odnac49q/

Comment: @RuiFernando forget to mention you in the comment above this one. Please have a look at the update fiddle mentioned there.

Comment: I'll try it out and give you some feedback